# Firestore error when setting new document data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is not my first time trying to do this in an app but it is the first time I've run into an error like this. Here is the code I'm using to set the data:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
  'username': usernameController.text,
  'snapchat': snapController.text,
  'email': emailController.text,
});
```

I've tried using the most recent plugin along with older versions but get the same error no matter what. The error seems to mean there's implementation missing for the set function but I don't see how that is possible across multiple versions. Everything firebase-related has been initialized in the app by this point and I am able to use authentication so I don't know what the issue is. Here's the error I get.

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore)
>
> #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)

I've also tried `flutter clean` and then `flutter packages get` but that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the project was using a pretty old version of dart. It is a project that I am taking over so I had no idea and that is why the newer plugins could not work properly. After upgrading the dart version, all plugins, and fixing all of the no longer supported code, firestore works fine.